# type ussd command and display result in textbox using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, ussd

I have a Windows Form in my project. This form contains 3 controls: `txtUss`, `btnCheck` and `txtMessage`. The scenario is that after a "ussd" command has been entered in the  `txtUss` text box and the `btnCheck` button has been pressed, the result will displayed in `txtMessage`.

here is the detail of my winform 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2lo8ci3rcoznvlh/ussd.PNG

btnCheck Code :

```
private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SerialPort port = new SerialPort();

        port.BaudRate = 115200;
        port.PortName = "COM3";
        port.Timeout = 300;

        port.Open();
        port.Write("AT+CUSD=1," + txtUssd.Text + ",15");

        txtMessage.text = ; // <<< here is the result. 
        // but i dont know how to refer port.Write("AT+CUSD=1," + txtUssd.Text + ",15");
        port.Close();               
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I don't know how to get the result in the `txtMessage` text box.

Any one can suggest me or give some example...?

**if you wanna get update solve for this question and topic checking balance in modem, follow this link :** 
[Check balance using USSD Command in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31677028/check-balance-using-ussd-command-in-c-sharp-solved)

Comment: can you please clarify the question? refer to the guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to receive the response from the COM port, you will need to add an event handler to your code, and register it with the COM port's `DataReceived` event, so that you can read the response when data is received, and display it in your `txtMessage` text box.

Because the event will be sent on a different thread, and it is not allowed to update the UI controls from a thread that did not create them, the update will take two steps, as shown in the method below that you will need to add to your form:

```
private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // read the response.
        var response = ((SerialPort)sender).ReadLine();

        // Need to update the txtMessage on the UI thread.
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => txtMessage.Text = response));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

In your `btnCheck_Click` method, after the line `port.Open();` you need to add the following line, to register the event handler:

```
port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
```

Another problem appears to be that you close the COM port immediately, possibly before the response is received. So I suggest you do the following:

1. Make `port` a member variable of your Form class (name it `_port`).

   ```
   private SerialPort _port
   ```
2. Create and open the COM port when your form is created:

   ```
   _port = new SerialPort();
   _port.BaudRate = 115200;
   _port.PortName = "COM3";
   _port.Timeout = 300;

   _port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
   _port.Open();
   ```
3. Close and dispose the COM port when your form is closed.

   ```
   _port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);        
   _port.Close();
   _port.Dispose();
   ```

Only keep this in your button click event handler:

```
private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        _port.Write("AT+CUSD=1," + txtUssd.Text + ",15");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: so it means that i must add some code (method port_DataReceived) in my project ? 
and adding `port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);` in btnCheck?

Comment: @aminvincent yes that is the idea. the `port_DataReceived` method can be a private method in your form.

Comment: thanks for your suggest,..when i run my project and click btnCheck disappear anything..... can u help me to fix my code above?

Comment: @aminvincent I am sorry, I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "when I click btnCheck disappear anything" ?

Comment: i have tried again for code above,..absolutely work...but the result just appear OK .....i don't know how to fix this...

Comment: @aminvincent I still don't quite understand what you mean. But I did find another problem with the code. I updated my answer to explain how you can solve it.

Comment: i have tried again code suggest from u above,..but it work fine. just my problem didn't solve,...when i click in btnCheck it always apper result in txtMessage = OK ...when i try ussd command AT+CUSD=1,\"*388#\",15 in hyperterminal it work fine bro,...i don't know.. this image result of my form 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/u73olhdnsebrqfc/result.png

Comment: @aminvincent, well I cannot debug your serial communication for you. You may need to check handshaking settings, ...., I can't know what is needed for your specific use case. I just provided a solution for you to display the serial communication response in a textbox, like you asked in your question.

Comment: ,..your suggest really work in my project to display it in my serial communication response in a textbox,...thanks....so finally i just resolve my code to fix how to serial communication work...