# Check balance using USSD Command in C#

Tags: c#, at-command, ussd

**I update for this question and know it worked correctly..**

I try to check balance in my mavecom modem but I got no response in my textbox. It stays empty.

Here my code :

```
private SerialPort _port;

private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _port = new SerialPort();
        _port.PortName = cbPort.Text;
        _port.BaudRate = 115200;
        _port.Parity = Parity.None;
        _port.DataBits = 8;
        _port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        _port.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend;

        port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
        port.Open();

        port.Write("AT+CUSD=1,\"" + txtUSSD.Text + "\",15" + "\r");
    }

private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // read the response.
            var response = ((SerialPort)sender).ReadLine();

            // Need to update the txtProvider on the UI thread .
            //showing result in txtOutput based on txtProvider USSD Command
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => txtOutput.Text = response)); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This is solved and can be use to check the balance....

Comment: Don't close the port right after you write to it.

Comment: Also good idea to register to `DataReceived` before opening the serial port.

Comment: let's i try first for your suggest

Comment: guys,..it still disappear...no result found at txtOutput

Comment: Don't add the words "[Solved]" to the title, that is not how it works. Tick the correct answer instead.

Comment: no correct answer for this question,.. i just fix it myself and wanna the other reader can know and use this sample code,.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good start, you are properly terminating AT command lines with `\r` (not using WriteLine or any other such incorrect approaches that unfortunately are common beginner problems). However the format of the command is defined in [27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm) to be

```
AT+CUSD=[<n>[,<str>[,<dcs>]]]
...
Defined values
...
<str>: string type USSD-string ...
```

and string parameters shall always be enclosed with double quotes ([V.250](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en) chapter 5.4.2.2 String constants: `String constants shall be bounded at the beginning and end by the double-quote character`).

So without knowing the textProvider object in detail I am quite confident that your code should be

```
port.Write("AT+CUSD=1,\"" + txtProvider.Text + "\",15" + "\r");
```

but note that if `txtProvider.Text` contains any `"` characters they must be escaped (*not* as `\"` by the way, check 5.4.2.2).

---

However even with the above fixed you need to seriously rework your reception handling. You **MUST** read and parse every single line of response from the modem until you get a Final result code back (most commonly `OK` or `ERROR`, but there are several others). Any other way cannot work reliably. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16446523/23118) for pseudo code structure of how to do it properly.

And as commented, you are closing the port too early.

Comment: `"\",15" + "\r"` could be just `"\",15\r"`

Comment: @hlovdal when i change ussd at command like `port.Write("AT+CUSD=1,\"" + txtProvider.Text + "\",15" + "\r");` nothing happen,...no result in txtOutput